# How to order a plot in ggvis in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggvis

I am trying to learn how to use `ggvis` to make plots. I really would like on that looks like this:

[image: Plot]

I have learned how to make a nearly identical plot:

```
library(ggvis)
y <- c(
"a",    "b",    "c",    "d",    "e",    "f",    "g",    "h",
"a",    "b",    "c",    "d",    "e",    "f",    "g",    "h")

x <- c(28, 25, 38, 19, 13, 30, 60, 18, 11, 10, 17, 13, 9, 25, 56, 17)
Status <- c(rep(c('Group 1'),8), rep(c('Group 2'),8))

df <- data.frame(y,x,Status)

df %>% ggvis(x= ~x, y= ~y, fill= ~Status) %>% layer_points() %>%
  add_axis('x', properties= axis_props( grid = list(stroke = 'blank') )) %>%
  add_axis('y', properties= axis_props( grid = list(stroke = 'blank') ))
```

My question: How can I order the plot like they have done in the top plot? It looks like they have ordered it from biggest to smallest somehow. Thanks!

Comment: This may not be the most efficient method but you can calculate the order of the levels by hand. In your code adding `lvl <- df %>% group_by(y) %>% summarise(total = sum(x)) %>% arrange(desc(total)) %>% select(y)` and `df$y <- factor(df$y, levels = lvl$y)` should order things correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
tbl_df(df) %>% 
  mutate(y=as.character(y), x=as.numeric(x)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(x)) %>% 
 ggvis(x= ~x, y= ~y, fill= ~Status) %>% layer_points() %>%
  add_axis('x', properties= axis_props( grid = list(stroke = 'blank') )) %>%
  add_axis('y', properties= axis_props( grid = list(stroke = 'blank') ))
```